# Swapping images upon slider open

Tags: javascript, slider

On the homepage of this site [csr.steelcase.com](http://csr.steelcase.com) I'm trying to make it to where when you click the "Read More" and the down arrow on the slider box, when it slides down and the type changes to "Close" I'm attempting to make the down arrow turn into an up arrow.

The code that controls this section of the site is in the footer.php:

```
  $('.slide-read-more,.slide-tab-down').click(function (e) {
      mySlider.pause();
      $('.slide-content').slideToggle('slow', 'swing', function () {
          if ($('.slide-content').is(":hidden")) {
              $('.slide-read-more').text('| | Read More | |');
          } else {
              $('.slide-read-more').text('| | Close | |');
          }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

I've created a new up arrow image and uploaded it to the images folder, as well as created a css rule for the new up arrow, I just don't know how to get the images to swap out.

```
.slide-tab-up {display:block; width:40px; height:43px; margin:0 0 0 358px; background:url(images/tab-upturn.png) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click function, try adding

```
$('.slide-tab-down').toggleClass('slide-tab-up');
```

As long as your `.slide-tab-up` styles override your `.slide-tab-down` styles, this should work.

On another note, I'd recommend putting the `e.preventDefault()` at the top of the function as well.

Comment: This won't work if you toggle slide-tab-down off... that selector would fail.

Comment: My edits should address that issue, but regardless, barring some change of strategy in the use of selectors, classes, and ids some combination of addClass, removeClass, and/or toggleClass is what will work here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding another generic class to the `<a>` that contains that image.  Lets call it "slider-img".  So in your markup below:

```
<div class="slide-read-more-wrap" style="text-align:center;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;">
        <a title="Read More" class="slide-read-more">| | Read More | |</a>
        <a href="#" title="" class="slide-tab-down slider-img"></a>
</div>
```

Then in your JS, in your slideToggle function, all you need is this line to toggle your slide-tab-down/slide-tab-up classes on .slider-img's element:

```
$('.slide-content').slideToggle('slow','swing', function(){
        $('.slider-img').toggleClass('slide-tab-up').toggleClass('slide-tab-down');

        if ($('.slide-content').is(":hidden")) {
              $('.slide-read-more').text('| | Read More | |');
        } else {
              $('.slide-read-more').text('| | Close | |');
        }
});
```